# What is the smallest scheduled transatlantic destination?

Tags: air-travel, europe, north-america

When travelling to North America, I am usually quite stressed when arriving in a large airport serving a huge city, so I like to seek out flights arriving in more peaceful settings.

Condor seasonally flies from Frankfurt to [Whitehorse International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erik_Nielsen_Whitehorse_International_Airport), an airport with (2014) 22,879 movements serving [a town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehorse,_Yukon) of around 25k people.

Air Saint Pierre seasonally flies from Paris CDG to [Saint-Pierre Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Pierre_Airport), serving [Saint Pierre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Pierre,_Saint_Pierre_and_Miquelon) with less than 6k inhabitants.

What is the smallest destination in the Americas I can fly to directly from Europe?  For smallest, I may consider either the size of the airport (by number of travellers, aircraft movements, or otherwise) or the population of the city/area it serves.  I consider only regularly scheduled flights, seasonal is fine, but not charters.  Islands geographically associated with the Americas count, except Greenland (because [Kangerlussuaq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangerlussuaq_Airport) is mostly a hub for transferring to smaller flights, and Greenland has, most of the time, *only* flights from Europe).

Is any destination smaller than Saint Pierre to which I can fly non-stop from Europe?

Comment: As a more practical consideration, would you consider the size of the immigration/customs checkpoint? I can think of a couple of airports in good sized cities but with very tiny immigration areas.

Comment: I will be exceptionally surprised if St Pierre isn't the smallest. It's a ridiculously small airport that wouldn't normally warrant anything bigger than a regional flight.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not sure.  The flight from Paris to Saint Pierre is domestic :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton [Stanley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley,_Falkland_Islands) is smaller, but not really in the Americas.  But maybe some other islands associated with Europe?

Comment: But what serves your question is actually the smallest on both ends.  Better two midsize cities like Flint MI than a small town like St Johns and a huge international hub like CDG.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica True... but that makes the question much harder to define and answer.

Comment: Smallest airport, or smallest city/state/country.  Bermuda?

Comment: Note: if it is just immigration that bother your, you may try London City to New York: you will do immigration and custom in Ireland (and a small aircraft). In NYC you enter as domestic flight.

Comment: How does a flight from London to New York do customs&immigration in Ireland?

Comment: @gerrit you have to change planes, as City can't handle transatlantic jets.  City is only an example as many routes allow you to "enter" the US before boarding in Ireland.  The same holds for some Canadian airports.

Comment: @ChrisH That's not a direct flight then... by that reasoning I can fly from Værøy to Page as two tiny airports... :)

Comment: Yes, @GiacomoCatenazzi's example wasn't the most direct example of entering the US while physically in Europe

Comment: No, it is a direct flight, from BA.Just that they need a stop in Ireland, because... London City has a short runway, so planes could not have too much fuel, so during refuelling there is custom and immigration check. Note: on the way back there is no stop (plant will have much less fuel when landing)

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder No.  My scheduled I mean regular non-charter.  Is "scheduled" the right choice as an antonym to "charter"?

Answer (score 4):

I googled unusual transatlantic flights and got this [USA Today article from 2018](https://www.usatoday.com/picture-gallery/travel/flights/2017/10/02/two-dozen-of-the-most-unusual-airline-routes-to-europe/106224344/) so no telling if all the flights are still flying...

Most entries had a big airport at one end or the other but this one stood out to me:

Providence, Rhode Island (PVD) to Ponta Delgada, Azores (PDL) on Azores Air. It's summer-seasonal.

Comment: Azores is only half transatlantic though :)

Comment: Unfortunately the USA Today article is apparently not available from the European Union (it redirects me to "welcome to our European Union experience").

Comment: @gerrit - sure, Azores isn't fully transatlantic.  But from there there are seasonal flights to (per Wikipedia) Faro or Bilbao, which aren't particularly large.

Answer (score 4):

[Samaná El Catey International Airport (AZS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saman%C3%A1_El_Catey_International_Airport) only has 858 aircraft movements a year, but still has seasonal transatlantic flights to Frankfurt operated by Condor.

[San Salvador Airport in the Bahamas (ZSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Salvador_Airport) has 896 movements a year. It has seasonal flights to Paris-Orly operated by Air Caraïbes. It is on San Salvador Island which has a population of 930.

[Picture of the latter seem to indicate a pretty relaxed airport.](https://www.flickr.com/photos/58572954@N00/171421713/)

For both, that's an average of less than 9 aircraft per week.